# How to call on init function from textarea with parameter?

Tags: angular

I have this function in component:

```
check(t){ 
  t.style.height = (t.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
}
```

in html i have this:

```
<textarea id="name" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
```

What i want is on init call this `check(this)`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is your component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template variables and @ViewChild to get hold of a textarea element and use it in ngAfterViewInit:

```
<textarea id="name" #text></textarea>



@ViewChild('text') textArea;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.textArea.nativeElement.style.height = (this.textArea.nativeElement.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: i dont know if u understand me i dont need onkeydown because i will not enter anything in textarea i will only display data so  i just want on start to pass that element and then get height of that element.

Comment: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined ... i get this error

Comment: @None, I missed this,can you try again

Comment: Now i get this: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined, i cannot access to property of textarea

Comment: nothing is happening when i do this:
console.log('height',this.textArea.nativeElement.style.height); i get only text height displayed and not value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148024/discussion-between-none-and-jayakrishnan-gounder).